# Set image opacity with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day! In all honesty the problem is a bit more complex. I want to know why the following line of code doesn't work:

```
pic.style.opacity = toString((5-z)/10);
```

Why I think it should work ?

- the opacity member variable is a string so it needs to be a string therefore as long as the "toString" method is there after the system calculates the expression it should be turned into a string and therefore it should be viable.

Note: z is an integer number which has a varying value from 0 to 4.

In case someone wants to test for themselves:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #asd{
            background-image : url(fry.jpg);
            margin-left:20%;
            margin-top:20%;
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="asd"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script
var z = 3;
function foo(){
   document.getElementById("asd").style.opacity = toString((5-z)/10);
}
foo();
    </script>
```

Comment: you don't need the .toString(); pic.style.opacity = ((5-z)/10); besides, .toString() works the other way around, ((5-z)/10).toString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont' need `toString`.

Just do:

```
document.getElementById("asd").style.opacity = (5-z)/10;
```

You aren't using `toString` correct anyway. If you'd like to use it anywhere, do it that way:

```
var number = 42.0;
var string = number.toString(10);
```

The `10` is optional and default. For instance you can use `2` to convert in dual system.

Comment: A JSFiddle to show that it works (I added a background color to illustrate the effect, since the image doesn't exist). http://jsfiddle.net/9tUjK/

Comment: If this fixed the problem you should select it.

Answer (score 2):

You are inadvertently calling `window.toString()`. The `toString` method is called as a method from the item you want to convert.

Also, you don't need it. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the document to load before trying to access/set opacity for any element. Check onLoad event of javascript or $(document).ready() if you are using jQuery.

By the way - your opening `script` tag has a missing > sign

Answer (score 0):

It'll work if you remove the toString. The value for opacity is a decimal value between 0.0 - 1.0

further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp